# Maxwell distribution solely using the Stosszahlansatz and geometric transformations?

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, specific-reference

### Background

To quote Wikipedia:

> The assumption of molecular chaos is the key ingredient that allows
> proceeding from the BBGKY hierarchy to Boltzmann's equation, by
> reducing the 2-particle distribution function showing up in the
> collision term to a product of 1-particle distributions.

But I believe I can derive the Maxwell Distribution solely using the molecular chaos (Stosszahlansatz)  and geometric transformation properties. I'm not aware of this argument in the literature.

### Question

Is there a derivation of the Maxwell distribution solely using the Stosszahlansatz and geometric transformations ([relative velocity composition law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relative_velocity#In_one_dimension_(non-relativistic))) in the literature?